# Database-first EF7-beta7 dnx ef dbcontext scaffold command fails

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, dnx, entity-framework-core

In an asp.net 5 beta 7 project no matter how the command is written I get an unrecognized argument trying to scaffold the dbcontext from an existing db:

```
C:\Dev\Project>dnx ef dbcontext scaffold provider EntityFramework.SqlServer connection 
    "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ubercrew_relation;Integrated Security=True"
```

I've tried all possible combinations of the two arguments connection and provider

Do you know the right syntax for executing the scaffold command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right command is:

> C:\Dev\Project>dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ubercrew_relation;Integrated Security=True" EntityFramework.SqlServer

Be sure to have installed the EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design package via nuGet